# How to creating EmptyDataText for DataGridView in Windows Application

Tags: winforms, datagridview, custom-controls

Today i am facing problem to show/hide label according to data source. If the data source has no row then **i would like to set "No Data Found"** else display number of records **in winforms application**.

This would be possible in Asp.net like:

```
<emptydatatemplate>
No Data Found
</emptydatatemplate>
```

OR

```
EmptyDataText=" No Data Found"
```

*But I would like in Windows Application*. Please help me if you have any solution for the same.

Any solution would be appreciated!
Thanks,
Imdadhusen

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way you could accomplish this is to use the Paint() event to check the rows and if there are none, then write your message:
Collapse

```
private void dataGridView1_Paint ( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
{
    DataGridView sndr = ( DataGridView )sender;

    if ( sndr.Rows.Count == 0 ) // <-- if there are no rows in the DataGridView when it paints, then it will create your message
    {
        using ( Graphics grfx = e.Graphics )
        {
            // create a white rectangle so text will be easily readable
            grfx.FillRectangle ( Brushes.White, new Rectangle ( new Point (), new Size ( sndr.Width, 25 ) ) );
            // write text on top of the white rectangle just created
            grfx.DrawString ( "No data returned", new Font ( "Arial", 12 ), Brushes.Black, new PointF ( 3, 3 ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks [JOAT-MON](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/190395/How-to-creating-EmptyDataText-for-DataGridView-in-.aspx) for accepted solution.

Thanks,
Imdadhusen

Comment: I found that the size needs to adjust to the grid height as well, not a hard-coded 25, so `new Size ( sndr.Width, sndr.Height)`

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm having troubles implementing this behavior using the Paint event, I solved by adding a panel to my form containing the graphics I want to show when no data is displayed (basically a couple of labels) and swap it with the grid when needed.