# DataGridView: View Empty Data Grid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

In my `DataGridView` controls, if there is no data to display, the control shows a blank screen.

What our spec calls for is something more like a blank screen in Microsoft Excel.

Is there a setting on the `DataGridView` control that I should specify for this or am I going to need to manually toss a number of blank rows into a `DataTable` to insert into there (never tried that)?

If I'd need to do that programmatically, what would be the best way to tell how many rows I should add to an empty `DataTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid but it looks like you will need to populate rows and columns dynamically. Take a look on following posts:

[Making a DataGridView look like an Excel sheet](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/374216)

Comment: That is what I was thinking I'd have to do.

Answer (score 2):

Setting DataGridView's Datasource property should show you the grid with atleast the columns (in GridView's heading) even when DataTable is empty. If you could paste the code that you use, it might help to debug.

Comment: There is no code yet. I'm developing the construct for our app. Someone else will be supplying the data code. I just need to show a DataGridView full of empty cells instead of a blank canvas for data to be displayed in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use something like "EmptyDataTemplate" of the GridView and display some static table with columns as you want.

Hope this could be of some help!!

Comment: This is a `DataGridView` (Windows Form). It doesn't have an `EmptyDataTemplate` like the `GridView` control. :(

Comment: Please check the below link which explains how to accomplish the same in win forms  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866458/how-to-creating-emptydatatext-for-datagridview-in-windows-application

Comment: +1 though, because searching for `EmptyDataTemplate` with `DataGridView` has shown me that lots of others have tried this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't see any problem in making something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_emptyrows; i++)
    {
        dgv.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
    }
```

This is naturally after then you defined all columns in grid.

Answer (score 1):

you can make an empty grid as below:

```
private void showemptygrid()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(string));


        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)  // add 20 empty rows
        {
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            dr["ID"] = "";
            dr["Name"] = "";
            dr["Date"] = "";
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        grid_logs.DataSource = table;
        grid_logs.DataBind();
    }
```

Obviously first you need to define a grid with these columns and set their related datafields.