# how to show custom message on empty datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

in my window form, i showing details of category to users using `datagridview`, but i also want to show a custom message when in my table there is no record found , then i want to show a custom message like 
"No Records founds" .
this message should be in `datagrird` view  like if you are familiar with `asp` where there is empty `data template` to show custom message in `gridview`
here is code for showing data in my `datagridview`

```
public void getData()
        {
            try
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(str);
                con.Open();
                string getAll = "select (CatID) as [ID],CategoryName as [Category Name] from Category order By CategoryName";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getAll, con);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "Category");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
                dataGridView1.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].ToString();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

and i called this method on form load.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no implemented way to do what you want.

After checking

```
if (ds.Rows.Count > 0)
```

, either way you have to place an own control, like a label, in front of your DGV 
OR you completely draw your message from hand on the DGV.

Easiest way would be to just prompt a Message.Box or to dismiss the DGV in the case there are now Rows in your dataset and show another control with your "No Recores found" message instead

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent property in `winforms datagridview`

You might look into the solution of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866458/how-to-creating-emptydatatext-for-datagridview-in-windows-application).